# Android UiAutomator - detect if app is in uiautomator mode

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I have an app which is purchasing products. During uiautomation testing I want to test whole views, but dont want it to purchase in real.

How to check in the testing application, if the device is running in ui-automator mode ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a system property before each test and after each test, you have to reset that flag.

```
//in setup            
execCommand(uiDevice, "setprop uiautomation.mode true");
//in teadDown
execCommand(uiDevice, "setprop uiautomation.mode false");
```

Comment: I assume, the execCommand method is UiDevice.executeShellCommand(...)

+1 thanks